# Impedance matching in common collector

Tags: power, amplifier, analog, bjt

The last stage of a power amplifier to an 8 ohm speaker is usually a common collector. Now many textbooks mention that it is used as a buffer as it has a low output impedance compared to the speaker (Zout << Z speaker). 
To me this is what people call voltage impedance matching as the full voltage of the amplifier is applied to the speaker.  But I always thought that what is of interest is the maximum power transfer. So what matters is power impedance matching which implies that Zout =Z speaker.
So which one is true :   voltage or power impedance matching in the last stage of a power AMPLIFIER?

Comment: I think you are confusing impedance bridging with impedance matching.

Comment: Audio amplifiers have an extremely low output impedance to damp the resonances of speakers so that the sound is not "boomy".

Answer (score 2):

There's some fixed resistance at the output of your buffer. And the matching is relative to that resistance.

If that output resistance was **fixed** 8 ohm, a 8 ohm speaker would indeed receive the max power, given the voltage of the buffer.

You'd be loosing power if the speaker was more than 8 ohms or less than 8 ohms.

But your speaker is fixed at 8 ohms, and there's little you could do about that.

**More importantly, the max power transfer idea starts with a fixed output resistance.**

So if the output resistance was fixed at 8 ohms, you'd best have an 8 ohm speaker.

If the output resistance was fixed at 50 ohms, you'd best have a 50 ohm speaker.

But in your case, you can control the output resistance of the buffer (if you design it), while you can't control the resistance of the speaker.

So you'd think, well if the speaker is 8 ohms, I'd better select a buffer output impedance of also 8 ohms.

That's tempting but that reverses the matching on its head. Yes, if the buffer impedance is ***already*** fixed at 8 ohms, you best have an 8 ohm speaker.

But if the buffer impedance is in your control, you should minimize it.

If you can make the buffer output resistance 0 ohms, your speaker will receive 100% of the power and 100% of the voltage (for a given buffer voltage).

If you can make the buffer output resistance 1 ohms, your speaker will receive 8/9 of the power and 8/9 of the voltage.

(And in both these case there would be more current, and therefore more power than in a matched 8 ohm - 8 ohm case. Of course, if you could reduce the speaker to 1 ohm, and the output resistance is 1 ohm, you'd be maximizing power to the speaker, at the cost of some voltage (to the speaker), but that's not in the cards, as the speaker is fixed at 8 ohms).

(It's true that common collectors are a way to drive a speaker, a slightly better way is AB class buffer\amplifier, because they don't need so much DC biasing.)

Comment: I've just realized it's an old question I've been answering. Oh well, maybe it's helpful to answer anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing two slightly different things.

When you're using an amplifier with a certain output impedance then you can extract the **maximum** power from it when the load impedance has the same value.

Example: a signal generator (like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RXDC2GR), they're used in electronics labs), these have "50 ohm" outputs and only when you load them with 50 ohms will you get the maximum power. A much higher or lower load will also just work but the **power** will always be less.

Audio amplifiers generally have a **very low** output impedance, like in the order of less than 1 ohm. If you impedance matched that with a very low impedance speaker you might think that you would get maximum power. Theoretically, yes you would **BUT** I have yet to see an amplifier that behaves that way (theoretically ideal I mean).

Real world amplifiers cannot deliver more than a certain amount of current and a certain amount of voltage. Since power = voltage x current, for maximum power you want voltage and current to be as large as possible.

That's where the recommended impedance (4 ohms, 8 ohms) comes in, that is the load impedance that will make the amplifier operate at it's maximum voltage and current that it can handle. Use a lower impedance and the current will become too large. Use a higher impedance and the current will be lower than the amplifier can deliver (you'd be wasting that current capability).

I'm deliberately not writing: "Use a higher impedance and the voltage will become too high" as that doesn't happen. Audio amplifiers are practically all **voltage output** amplifiers which means that they amplify the input signal (also a voltage) to an output voltage. The current will depend on the load. Without a load, you still get the voltage. With a load that is too low, too much current will flow and the amplifier will clip (distort) and/or switch off to protect itself and/or can be damaged.

Comment: A speaker has a low resonant frequency that sounds like a bongo drum when it is not damped. An amplifier usually has an extremely low output impedance that damps the resonances. The amplifier spec is called its "Damping Ratio". Some good amplifiers have a damping ratio >1500 then its output impedance is less than 0.0053 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way.

If you had a 12 volt light bulb that has a resistance of 12 ohms and you applied it to a 12 volt power supply, it would produce a certain amount of brightness based on the power consumed.

Then, you insert a 12 ohms resistor in series with the bulb and looked at the bulb’s brightness.

In which scenario is the bulb the brightest?

<sub>In your question you are putting the cart before the horse and assuming maximum power is obtained when the source impedance matches the load impedance. In fact it’s when the load impedance matches the source impedance that you have the maximum power scenario.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In a power amplifier the designer is typically trying to present a perfect, undistorted voltage signal to the speaker. The output voltage should simply be the input voltage multiplied by the gain of the amplifier. You get this in part by having your source impedance be much lower than the load impedance.

Without this buffer there would be some voltage dropped across the power transistor and some across the speaker. The amount of drop across the transistor would be dependent on the instantaneous current through the transistor. Since this current varies from one instant to another, the voltage across the transistor would also vary from moment to moment, causing distortion in the output voltage.

As a side note: Zout << Zload results in high efficiency as opposed to maximum power transfer. As Zout drops, more power is dissipated in Zload, less in Zout.

Comment: OK. So if I understand correctly,  in the last stage of a power amplifier we have impedance  bridging( so as to have the maximum voltage applied to the speaker) not impedance matching ( so as to have a maximum transfer of power from the source to the speaker).

Comment: Yes, that's a fair way to say it.